# Gerrit code review, or Github's fork and pull model?

Tags: github, gerrit, pull-request

I am starting a software project that will be team AND community developed. I was previously sold on gerrit, but now github's fork and pull request model seem to almost provide more tools, ways to visualize commits, and ease of use.

For someone who has at least a little experience with both, what are the pros/cons of each, and which would be better for a team based project which wants to leave open the possibility for community development?

Comment: You might want to consider to post this question on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) instead of here.